# AngularJS $compile removes previous compiled-element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-compile

**Background**

We have an old application written i jQuery and Handlebars and we're migrating part by part to AngularJS (this work began many years ago and was never finished, hence AngularJS).

**Problem**

To migrate part by part we're injecting directives into the old Handelbars-templates for several different reasons. The problem that I'm facing is that I can't `$compile` two different directives in the same view because, what it seems, one of the directives empties the other directive.

I can get around this by setting a timeout around one directive but I don't see that as a valid workaround so I'm hoping that it can be done in some other way.

**Relevant code**

This is how we load directives into a Handlebars-template:

```
<div id="ng-wrapper"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        angular.element(document).injector().invoke(['$compile', function ($compile) {
            var wrapperEl = $('ng-wrapper');
            var scope = angular.element(wrapperEl).scope();
            wrapperEl.append($compile('<directive-one></directive-one>')(scope);
        }]);
    });
</script>
```

If I try to add a second directive into that invoke-function one directive is emptied and only one directive is showing, like this:

```
<div id="ng-wrapper"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        angular.element(document).injector().invoke(['$compile', function ($compile) {
            var wrapperEl = $('ng-wrapper');
            var scope = angular.element(wrapperEl).scope();
            wrapperEl.append($compile('<directive-one></directive-one>')(scope);
            wrapperEl.append($compile('<directive-two></directive-two>')(scope);
        }]);
    });
</script>
```

If I however add a timeout it works, like this:

```
<div id="ng-wrapper"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        angular.element(document).injector().invoke(['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
            var wrapperEl = $('ng-wrapper');
            var scope = angular.element(wrapperEl).scope();
            wrapperEl.append($compile('<directive-one></directive-one>')(scope);
            $timeout(function () {
                wrapperEl.append($compile('<directive-two></directive-two>')(scope);
            }, 500);
        }]);
    });
</script>
```

I've used AngularJS for many years but haven't touched `$compile` before so hopefully it's something I'm doing wrong here :)

Comment: It should be `wrapperEl.append($compile('<directive-one></directive-one>')(scope))`. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that replicates the problem. This may depend on what the directives are. A plunk would be appropriate here.

Comment: @estus Thanks for keeping me straight :)
I've created a plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/1LmyTuSImFFER4FHPnHG and it works as it should. So the answer is that it's something else wrong with our application I guess *sigh* Thanks for your time :)

Comment: No problem. I'd suggest to look more closely how these directives work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it works as the first example (see the Plunker-URL in my comment) and that it's something else wrong in our application.